# C# ActiveMQ NMS Consumer -How to check if connection is broken with producer?

Tags: c#, connection, activemq-classic, consumer, nms

We are using apache-activemq-5.15.12- NMS client c# as consumer.
We are using topic. No acknowledgement is required.
Connection string is failover:(tcp://localhost:61616)?transport.timeout=10000&maxReconnectAttempts=1. (Trying to reproduce this with my localhost.)
Purpose is to throw exception when broker is down or any network connection issue.
But consumer hangs, and not receiving any Error.
How to check if connection is broken with message producer?

Comment: If using failover what is the purpose of needing to know there was a disconnection

Comment: Wants to troubleshoot issue of durable consumer hangs.In ActiveMQ console it is showing as connected  'Active Durable Topic Subscribers'. But it stops receiving message. So wanted to check if it is still connected. I have posted question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63458417/activemq-nms-client-durable-subscriber-stopped-receiving-messages
How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: provide more details in the question, code snippet of what your consumer does etc.

Comment: Code provided in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63458417/activemq-nms-client-durable-subscriber-stopped-receiving-messages

Comment: My issue is connection shows active- but not receiving messages.